# Logging out of HomeWindow to MainWindow

Tags: c#, wpf

I have two wpf window:  MainWindow.xaml where user will login and Homewindow.xaml which is displayed upon successful login. A menu item in HomeWndow.xaml has Log Out option. When user logs out of the HomeWindow I want to display MainWindow to restart the Login Process. Inside AppLogOut_Click button if I use this.Close() It closes both MainWindow.xaml and HomeWindow.xaml and if I use App.Current.Mainwindow.Close(), It doesn't close the HomeWindow and opens the MainWindow. Here are my codes. Any help will be appreciated.

```
private void HmWindow_Closing(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
{
    MessageBoxResult result = MessageBox.Show(this, "Are you sure you want to exit?", "Confirm!", MessageBoxButton.YesNo, MessageBoxImage.Question);
    if (result == MessageBoxResult.Yes)
    {
        Application.Current.Shutdown();
    }
}

private void AppLogOut_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    MainWindow mw = new MainWindow();
    mw.InitializeComponent();
    mw.Show();
    //this.Close();
    App.Current.MainWindow.Close();
}

private void AppExit_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Application.Current.Shutdown();
}
```

Comment: instead of closing the MainWindow on login try hiding it with mw.Hide(); and unhide it when you log out

Comment: Have a look at `App.ShutdownMode`, it should be the most likely reason for your app closing completely when you close a specific window

Comment: @Denis Schaf, so if I do this.Hide(), I need to unhide the mainwindow from HomeWindow, how would I unhide the same window? If I do 
'''HomeWindow hw = new HomeWindow();
hw.show()'''
It creates new object, how do I show the same window that I hide ?

Answer (score 0):

This all depeneds on the [ShutdownMode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.application.shutdownmode?view=netframework-4.7.2). Default value is OnLastWindowClosed and if you close the last window that is opened this will force the application to shutdown.